# Apache authentication from multiple domains in AD

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm trying to find out if there are any apache modules which would allow me to authenticate from 2 different domains of same forest in AD

I have used AuthLDAPURL , AuthLDAPBindDN but they have limitation , they work well if authentication is happening from single domain but not multiple domains .

Has any one made apache authenticate from multiple domains , if yes which module did you use?

Comment: it'd work better if you showed what you tried, that'd give us a better idea of what you'retrying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using authentication aliases using mod_authn_alias. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authn_alias.html